# .split & .strip to delete spaces and tags

Tags: python, tags

I am trying to use the .split and .strip built in functions of python to get data within tags from a file.

```
file = open("testFile.txt")
for pointlessVariableName in file:
    teamName = pointlessVariableName.strip().split("<name></team>")
for i in range(0,len(teamName)):
    teamName[i] = teamName[i].strip()
```

I am not entirely familiar with these two, but the goal is to get rid of the tags "" and "" and get rid of the spaces before and after the words inside the tags.

Comment: what is the structure of you data file? you could paste snippet of it here

Comment: the structure is as follows:
<team> New England Patriots </team>
<name> Tom Brady </name>
<height> 5-11 </height>

etc... there are multiple of each (having trouble posting to your page)

Answer (score 1):

if your data is well formed XML, use a proper XML parser, it is clumsy to parse structured data with `split/strip`.

if you still want parse it by hand, use regex.

Comment: Could you go into more detail on parsing it by hand? Thanks. I know that it may not be the most efficient parsing with those two, just attempting to do so.

Comment: you could paste more lines of you data to pastebin.com for further investigation.

Comment: Essentially, I want to remove the tags from each of these (to eventually summarize). http://pastebin.com/GNLytFbU. I was planning on creating a loop that goes through the amount of times there are <player> tags, and then writing the new file each time it goes through finding the new tag. Hopefully this makes more sense.

Comment: I have checked your data, it  is much harder to parse it by hand then use a xml parer, you could read this http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/scenarios/xml/

Answer (score -1):

you can try this code block:

```
from w3lib.html import remove_tags
file = open("testFile.txt")
for pointlessVariableName in file:
    teamName = map(str,remove_tags(pointlessVariableName).split())
    print(teamName)
```

Output :

```
['New', 'England', 'Patriots', 'Tom', 'Brady', '5-11']
```

Comment: op didnt say the data is HTML.

Comment: But the file structure is like html : opening and closing tags

Comment: i have to say that is a bold conclusion.